# Issues zeroing an LVM volume

Tags: linux, lvm, dd

I have a system with two LVM volumes on an eMMC device, and I'm trying to "wipe" one of the volumes by filling it with zeros. This is my first time working with LVM, so I'll show what I tried and didn't have luck with.

First I used `pvdisplay -m` to see how my volumes are set up:

```
# pvdisplay -m
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mmcblk0p2
  VG Name               vg0
  PV Size               3.42 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              876
  Free PE               776
  Allocated PE          100
  PV UUID               i2Abz2-4o2h-9hq4-Gk3h-b5SD-0r9M-7oDfh3

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 49:
    Logical volume      /dev/vg0/volume_a
    Logical extents     0 to 49
  Physical extent 50 to 99:
    Logical volume      /dev/vg0/volume_b
    Logical extents     0 to 49
  Physical extent 100 to 875:
    FREE
```

This seems straightforward

- There is one VG, `vg0`
- `vg0` consists of one PV, `/dev/mmcblk0p2`
- The PV is 3.42GiB, split into 876 4MiB PEs
- PEs [0, 49] are storing the first LV, `volume_a`
- PEs [50, 99] are storing the second LV, `volume_b`

With this in mind, I went ahead and tried to zero out `volume_b` with `dd`:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/vg0/volume_b bs=1M count=200
201+0 records in
200+0 records out
209715200 bytes (210 MB, 200 MiB) copied, 17.2374 s, 12.2 MB/s
```

Based on the output of `pvdisplay -m`, I assumed that PEs [50, 99] (200M-400M) of `/dev/mmcblk0p2` should be filled with zeros. But here's what I saw:

```
# hexdump /dev/mmcblk0p2 -s 200m
c800000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
c900400 c800 0000 2000 0003 2800 0000 f0ad 0002
c900410 c7f5 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

There are some zeros, but only for 1MiB. I then tried filling it with random numbers and re-checked it.

```
# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/vg0/volume_b bs=1M count=200
200+0 records in
200+0 records out
209715200 bytes (210 MB, 200 MiB) copied, 99.9135 s, 2.1 MB/s
# hexdump /dev/mmcblk0p2 -s 200m
c800000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
c900400 c800 0000 2000 0003 2800 0000 f0ad 0002
c900410 c7f5 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

This is the same as before, so it appears like my `dd` calls aren't doing what I think they're doing. My assumption is that the LV `/dev/vg0/volume_b` is a kind of "virtual" block device, and when I use `dd` to write into it, LVM maps this to actual block writes to the corresponding PEs. Unfortunately this doesn't align with what I'm seeing.

[edit1] I used `hexdump` to check the contents of `/dev/vg0/volume_b` and, unsurprisingly, it's filled with random garbage. It just dawned on me to `hexdump` the entire `/dev/mmcblk0p2` and use `grep` to find where the data is stored. This is currently chugging along and I'll update this if it works.

[edit2] The search turned up nothing

Comment: To see the actual mapping between LV and underlying device, see `dmsetup table` output. See also `pvs -o all | less -S` to see where the first PE is located in a PV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more testing, it looks like there is an issue with LVM and its relationship with the Linux kernel. I'm guessing that it involves disk caching but I'm not 100% sure. Here's what I found:

First I wrote some garbage data to my LVM volume:

```
# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/vg0/volume_b bs=1M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.600447 s, 1.7 MB/s
```

Then, I read back the LVM volume. Here's a snippet of the garbage that was written:

```
# hexdump /dev/vg0/volume_b -n 0x20
0000000 2358 898b a13b 8d94 39a1 bff6 8b38 79ec
0000010 9155 1202 ce46 938f 49dc 7687 f804 bf13
0000020
```

But checking the block device itself, nothing lined up.

```
# hexdump /dev/mmcblk0p2 -s 200M
c800000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
c900000 2dee 8ea4 2116 1981 252f d113 afc1 3182
c900010 e6fc 7d1b d173 3cab 4399 8715 bcdf 2272
```

There was 1MiB of zeros followed by some garbage that doesn't line up with what was just written to the LVM volume. But just for kicks, I tried restarting the system and checking again.

```
# hexdump /dev/mmcblk0p2 -s 200M
c800000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
c900000 2358 898b a13b 8d94 39a1 bff6 8b38 79ec
c900010 9155 1202 ce46 938f 49dc 7687 f804 bf13
```

There's the data! There is still a 1MiB section of zeros (presumably a header?), but the data that was written to `/dev/vg0/volume_b` is there on `/dev/mmcblk0p2`.

I can't really explain this. My guess is that there may be an issue with the link between LVM and the kernel driver, or, more specifically, how the kernel handles disk caching. If I write to a physical disk through an LV to an area that is currently cached, is it possible that the cache won't be updated or marked as dirty?

This is an embedded system, so I've tried restarting my system by removing and re-applying power. The behaviour is exactly the same. Right up until power loss, `hexdump` on the physical device shows the stale data, and after rebooting it updates to the newly written data. This suggests that the writes are flushed to disk as they complete, and it isn't some part of Linux's power-off process.

I'll leave this open for a while since I'm still unsure what the root cause of this is, but at least I know that the problem isn't really a problem.

[edit] It definitely looks like the cache is to blame. Running `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` after the write causes the readback to immediately update. Welp.